# After update: `/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/md5sums': Is a directory

Tags: apt, update-manager, updates, dpkg

after updating my system today the following showed up. This is the result of running `apt-get install -f`:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libjna-java libswing-layout-java libofx4 libosp5 libgsasl7 javahelp2
  fairymax libequinox-osgi-java libfelix-main-java libntlm0 python-enchant
  visualvm libfelix-framework-java libgtkglext1 python-storm
  libnb-platform12-java msmtp
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdbus-1-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libdbus-1-dev
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0B/25.9kB of archives.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
(Reading database ... 
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `linux-firmware' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
(Reading database ... 516716 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libdbus-1-dev 1.4.0-0ubuntu1.1 (using .../libdbus-1-dev_1.4.0-0ubuntu1.2_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libdbus-1-dev ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libdbus-1-dev_1.4.0-0ubuntu1.2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 unable to install (supposed) new info file `/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/md5sums': Is a directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdbus-1-dev_1.4.0-0ubuntu1.2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The remark about the files list for linux-firmware missing is because I deleted those, as this was contributed as a solution to this problem. However, it didn't work out...

Any help would be most appreciated, since I can no longer do any installations at all!

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards

Comment: I had a similar issue. In my case, the message `unable to install (supposed) new info file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/md5sums': Is a directory` tried to tell me, that `/var/lib/dpkg/info/[PACKAGENAME].md5sums` should be a file, but is a directory.